# ember-pikaday does not create action when value is changed to null

Tags: ember.js

I'm using ember-pikaday on my web application. I have faced a problem while I'm testing my date component. When the value is set to null, it does not create action, and the binding value remains the last setted value. This is my component:

```
{{pikaday-input onSelection=(action 'onSelection') }}
```

This is my test.

```
import { moduleForComponent, test } from 'ember-qunit';
import hbs from 'htmlbars-inline-precompile';
import moment from 'moment';

moduleForComponent('my-component', 'TODO: put something here', {
  integration: true
});

 function updateDateValue(_this, val){
   let datecomponent = _this.$('input');
   datecomponent.click();
   datecomponent.val(val);
   datecomponent[0].dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
 }

  test('it renders', function(assert) {

  let actionListenerValue;
  this.on('myaction', function(val) { actionListenerValue=val; });

  this.render(hbs`{{my-component onSelection=(action 'myaction') }}`);

  updateDateValue(this, '01.04.2016');

  assert.equal(this.$('input').val(), '01.04.2016');
  assert.equal(moment(actionListenerValue).format('DD.MM.YYYY'), '01.04.2016');

  updateDateValue(this, '05.02.2016');
  assert.equal(this.$('input').val(), '05.02.2016');
  assert.equal(moment(actionListenerValue).format('DD.MM.YYYY'), '05.02.2016');

  updateDateValue(this, null);
  assert.notOk(this.$('input').val());
  assert.notOk(actionListenerValue); // this line throws error

});
```

I have prepared a [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/e3990522af32525bbb28fe6f1b8d49f6?openFiles=tests.integration.components.my-component-test.js%2C) of my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer on [ember-pikaday's test codes](https://github.com/edgycircle/ember-pikaday/blob/master/tests/integration/components/pikaday-input-test.js#L21).

The answer is to click anywhere in the context after setting value to null like this:

```
updateDateValue(this, null);
this.$().click();
```